# How to use custom scripts in Azure Data Factory to Transform data?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

We are currently using DataStage for ETL processing. We have lot of custom scripts to transform the data - eg

> if value of this column is X then set the value to XX

We are in the process of replacing DataStage with Azure Data Factory.

> Does Azure Data Factory has the capability to use the custom scripts for Transformation? If so, any reference.

Comment: Yes, in data flow we can write expressions to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the **case** expression in the Data flow `derived column` transformation in **Azure Data Factory**.

**Example:**

[image]

[image]